# Need to override custom module a phtml file and a Magento theme template file

Tags: magento2

I am using the default Magento Luma theme in Magento2. I would like to change in this file and need to override the `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml` file in the `app/code` folder.

I also want to change in existing custom module template file to override:

`app/code/company/modulename/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml`

I have tried lot of methods, but they're not working.

Answer (score -1):

Please Follow Below Instructions :

1.>> You want to override any Vendor/Extension/Module .PHTML file. You need to create your own theme. after that, you will override .PHTML file.

2.>> Click here to know how to create theme  https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/

3.>> app/design/frontend/Custom Package Name/Custom Theme Name/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml